# Unable to read schema from Extensible Storage using Design Automation for Revit

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk, forge, autodesk-designautomation

Do I have the possibility to read Extensible Storage from Design Automation?
Because when I use the same dll and the same addin file like in desktop Revit, but  I am not able to read schema. The Access level set to the vendor and I add to addin file correct vendor id.

On the desktop app, this dll works perfectly, but on the design automation I have the next issue in the report
[report screencapture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ef8t8.png)

Comment: Do the `AddInId` and the `VendorId` both match the one in Desktop addin?

Comment: @RahulBhobe Yup, all the same

Comment: What is the [access level](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2016/60600a74-450d-a175-ce3d-12e91fb22cd2.htm)?

Comment: @RahulBhobe 

schemaBuilder.SetReadAccessLevel(AccessLevel.Vendor);
schemaBuilder.SetWriteAccessLevel(AccessLevel.Vendor);

 I had the same behavior on the desktop when I first set wrong vendor id and Revit just remembered it, I fixed only after restarting of the computer

Comment: So is the issue resolved now?

Comment: @JeremyTammik same problem. 
I use the same dll and addin file, and on pc always all works perfect, but on design automation, I have an error about access to the schema

Comment: Then I would suggest sharing a minimal reproducible case that runs on the desktop and fails in DA4R: https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#1b

Comment: @JeremyTammik just to be sure, do you have any restriction about access to extensible storage using DA4R ?

Comment: @JeremyTammik I performed the next test. Created an empty Revit file. After that, I initialized extensible storage using the extension and added some data. Next, I Uploaded the file on the bucket. Uploaded the same dll and addin file on DA4R. Tried to read schema. Unsuccessful: `Reading of Entities of this Schema is not allowed to the current add-in`.

Comment: Earlier I had the same behavior on the Desktop Revit app. It remembered vendor id, and even when I changed it Revit continued using the old id. It was fixed by itself after restarting pc.

Comment: @JeremyTammik do you prefer some specific storage to share reproducible case? And if it possible I don't want to share for all networks, just for specific people.

Comment: @j.doe Please create a non-confidential minimal reproducible case that can be shared with all. Use any schema you like, just keep it minimal and fool-proof. According to your description, the schema definition hardly matters. The problem should be reproducible with a single click, more or less. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, can you try yo set the access level to visible for everybody, just to see whether that works at all? Try to narrow down the problem a bit?

Comment: Any news? Any change? Any sample forthcoming?